# How can use SL4J to log Exceptions from beans defined in applicationContext.xml in a separate file

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j

I'm using Markers to log some logs in a separate file.
But how can I use marker or something else to log an exception from bean defined in applicationContext.xml in a separate file? 
For example if I define a bean that has init-method throws JMSException.
How can I log this exception in a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use `@ControllerAdvice`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler{

//@Autowire logger here

    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public MyErrorDTO exception(MyCustomException e) {
        //log somewhere here
        return new MyErrorDTO(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by MyErrorDTO  and this method work? Can you give me an example? @xenteros

Comment: @user3475806 it's custom class you can create to return anything. Method can also by void. Yes, this will work :)